# When i try to create a table, i get an error

Tags: mysql

mysql.  For some reason I keep getting an error whenever I try to do. It says "create" is not valid at this position. Ive tried putting ; after create table but I still get that

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  home_country varchar(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Favourites (

UserID INT NOT NULL,

BandID INT NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY(UserID, BandID),

FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES User (ID),

FOREIGN KEY (BandID) REFERENCES Band (bid)

);
```

Comment: `user` is reserved word in MySQL. Try using another word, or surround it with backticks ```

Comment: @hermanto user is NOT a reserved word in MySQL

Comment: @Timothy : there is no delimiter at the end of your first CREATE TABLE statement